# in R, plot sucessive/sequence events

Tags: r, ggplot2, rcharts, sequence-diagram

EDITED: following the recommendation

I am trying to create a simple plot of the frequency of consecutive events based on this post: [ggplot sequence patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476090/ggplot-sequence-patterns)

I would like to pile up the same plot but for others subjects ( different sequences)
Subjects `"aa", "bb", "cc"`

The example dataset is as follow:

```
subject <- c("aa","aa","aa","aa","aa","aa","aa", "bb","bb","bb","bb","bb","bb","bb","cc","cc","cc","cc","cc","cc","cc")
event <- c("P","C","D","C","P","E","D","C","P","E","D","P","C","E","P","E","D","P","C","x","x")
freq <- c(3,2,1,4,2,1,0,3,4,1,3,3,1,2,1,3,2,1,4,0,0))

dfx <- data.frame(subject, event, freq)
```

The result I get is:
[image: my result, bad]

Using this code, based on the original post:

```
library(ggplot2)

dfx$type <- factor(dfx$type)
dfx$ymin <- c(0,1,2)
dfx$ymax <- c(1,2,3)
dfx$xmax <- cumsum(dfx$count)
dfx$xmin <- c(0, head(dfx$xmax, n=-1))

plot_x <- ggplot(dfx, 
            aes(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax,fill=type))   +geom_rect(colour="grey40", size=0.5)

png("plot_x.png", height=200, width=800)
print(plot_x)
dev.off()
```

I have created this image with what I would like to plot. ( it is handmade in excel). In this case, we have 3 subjects, 4 events (C,P, D,E)+1 dummy event(X), necessary to create the data frame. As you can see, the total number of events is not necessary equal on each subject.
[image: expected]

Comment: You should also share the code for the "result you got" part.

Comment: The example of what output you are aiming for would be easier to understand if it related to the example data you are providing. Either give the data behind the example as you have it, or make an example that matches the data as you have it

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations!. I have edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap`

```
library(ggplot2)
p1  <-  
    ggplot(dfx, aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, fill = event))+
    theme_bw() + 
    geom_rect(colour = "black", size = 0.5) + 
    facet_grid(subject ~ .) + 
    theme(axis.ticks.y=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_blank())

p1
```

[image]
DATA:

```
dfx <- data.frame(
       subject = c("aa","aa","aa","aa","aa","aa","aa", "bb","bb","bb","bb","bb","bb","bb","cc","cc","cc","cc","cc","cc","cc"),
       event = c("P","C","D","C","P","E","D","C","P","E","D","P","C","E","P","E","D","P","C","x","x"),
       freq = c(3,2,1,4,2,1,0,3,4,1,3,3,1,2,1,3,2,1,4,0,0),
       ymin = 0,
       ymax = 1)

TEMP        <-  tapply(dfx$freq,dfx$subject,cumsum)
dfx$xmax    <-  unlist(TEMP)
dfx$xmin    <-  c(0, head(TEMP$aa, -1), 0, head(TEMP$bb, -1), 0, head(TEMP$cc, -1))
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tested it and it a relly simple and good solution. Thanks a lot!!!